# QML: Will the Ubuntu Phone be theme-able, and do I need to develop with that in mind?

Tags: application-development, themes, ubuntu-sdk, qml, html

Take a simple example in formatting richtext:

The Manual Way

```
someTextBox.insert(0,"<font face='Ubuntu Mono'size='3'color='#f37420'> Blah Blah Blah </font>")
```

The hypothetical Way

```
someTextBox.insert(0,"<font face='" + phoneTheme.monoFont + "'size='3' color='" + phoneTheme.colorText +  "'> Blah Blah Blah </font>")
```

The manual way may become problematic if the user decides he wants orange backgrounds, making my text unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. The Ubuntu UI Toolkit provides a default theme, but there is no setting to use a different theme. A different random theme might entirely change how the UI functions, as well as looks, and might not work well on touch based devices.

However, in your app, you can specify some different colors for things. You'll notice for example that the Calendar, Calculator, Music, and other apps do not all have the same colors for everything, but the layout and functionality is generally consistent, and they do look like they all belong on the same system. That is how Ubuntu for phones is designed to be.

Apps are confined, so the user won't be able to change the background color in your app, unless your app specifically provides some way to do it.